# Найти определенные элементы на странице (jquery)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

На странице есть html код (динамический)

```
<div class="mes-cont" id="chat-window">
  <div class="mes mine" id="pm4436" data-id="4436"></div>
  <div class="mes mine" id="pm4438" data-id="4438"></div>
  <div class="mes " id="pm4446" data-id="4446"></div>
  <div class="mes mine" id="pm4449" data-id="4449"></div>
  <div class="mes " id="pm4450" data-id="4450"></div>
  <div class="mes mine" id="pm4451" data-id="4451"></div>
  <div class="mes " id="pm4452" data-id="4452" style="background-color: #E7E7E7 !important;"></div>
  <div class="mes " id="pm4453" data-id="4453" style=""></div>
  <div class="mes " id="pm4455" data-id="4455" style="background-color: #E7E7E7 !important;"></div>
  <div id="new_id"></div>
  <div class="mes " id="pm4456" style="background-color: #E7E7E7 !important;"></div>
</div>
```

Код ниже находит все data-id и формирует из них массив

```
<script language="javascript">
    var ArrList = $("#chat-window .mes").map(function(){
        return $(this).attr("data-id");
    }).get();
    alert(ArrList);
</script>
```

Нужно код который в javascript изменить так, чтобы он добавлял data-id в массив только при условии, что style="", либо style вообще отсутствует...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использовать `:not` что бы выбрать элементы без атрибутов, использовать `[style='']` что бы выбрать пустые атрибуты и использовать объединение селекторов: `#chat-window .mes:not([style]), #chat-window .mes[style='']`

```js
var ArrList = $("#chat-window .mes:not([style]), #chat-window .mes[style='']").map(function(){
    return $(this).attr("data-id");
}).get();
console.log(ArrList);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mes-cont" id="chat-window">
  <div class="mes mine" id="pm4436" data-id="4436"></div>
  <div class="mes mine" id="pm4438" data-id="4438"></div>
  <div class="mes " id="pm4446" data-id="4446"></div>
  <div class="mes mine" id="pm4449" data-id="4449"></div>
  <div class="mes " id="pm4450" data-id="4450"></div>
  <div class="mes mine" id="pm4451" data-id="4451"></div>
  <div class="mes " id="pm4452" data-id="4452" style="background-color: #E7E7E7 !important;"></div>
  <div class="mes " id="pm4453" data-id="4453" style=""></div>
  <div class="mes " id="pm4455" data-id="4455" style="background-color: #E7E7E7 !important;"></div>
  <div id="new_id"></div>
  <div class="mes " id="pm4456" style="background-color: #E7E7E7 !important;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Да, все верно, спасибо большое, работает...

Comment: а как найти все блоки #chat-window .mes определенного цвета (background-color) например цветом #E7E7E7?

Comment: [pre]var ArrList = $("#chat-window .mes:not([style]), #chat-window .mes[style='']").map(function(){
    return $(this).attr("data-id");
}).get();
console.log(ArrList);[/pre]